# Can someone explain this java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException to me

Tags: java, arrays

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class TwelveInts {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int bucky[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
        System.out.println("First to last: ");
        for(int i = 0; i<bucky.length; i++){
            System.out.print(bucky[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("Opposite order :) ");
        **for(int i = bucky.length; i >=0; i--){**
            System.out.print(bucky[i] + " ");
        }


    }

}
```

I realize that the line of problematic code is this:

```
for(int i = bucky.length; i >=0; i--)
```

It should be written as follows to get rid of the exception:

```
for(int i = bucky.length - 1; i >=0; i--){
```

I just don't understand why though. I know that the reason is because it's due to an illegal index, but I just don't understand this exception error in application to this problem. If someone can help me understand why this exception occurs in this problem without the "**-1"**, that would be great. I'm just having a really hard time visualizing it for this.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Because arrays are 0 based, and the length of the array is the number of elements. `int[] bucky = { 1, 2, 3};` The length of the array is 3, but has elements [0], [1], [2]. If you try to access `bucky[bucky.length]` that is [3] which doesn't exist in this example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The index of arrays and lists are 0-based.

So the first element of the array is accessed with `array[0]`, the last element is accessed with `array[array.length - 1]`

Zero-based indices are used in nearly all programming languages. There are good reasons for doing so, as eloquently explained by Edsger Dijkstra here: https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html.

Comment: i really appreciate your answer. I think I honestly had a brain fart...Thanks for clearing this up :)

Answer (score 1):

Because the indexing is starting from 0, though the when you are addressing size it does not count zero so if you have 2 element inside, the first will be addressed at index 0, but the size will be 2 of the array, so by saying size 2 you address a non existing index.

for instance:

int []array={1,2,3}; // the size is 3, so array.length will return 3.
but the last index will be 2 as indexing starts from 0. so if you address 3 it will be an exception out of bounds

Answer (score 1):

`for(int i = bucky.length - 1; i >=0; i--)` is the problem,

Arrays and lists beginn with the index 0

Imagine you have an array of `String[] a =  {A, B, C, D}`

So the length of the array is 4, because it contains 4 elements. So `a.length == 4`.
However, the first element of the array has the index 0 (and not 1).
Therefore

```
a[0] = A
a[1] = B
a[2] = C
a[3] = D
```

But `a[4]` is out of bounds

Answer (score 1):

For this array:

```
int bucky[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
```

bucky.length is 12 (array has 12 elements) therefore the indexes are from 0 to 11 (arrays are always zero based). Do not confuse the elements in the array with the indexes themselves (bucky[0], bucky[1], ... bucky[11]).

So, for reverse order you need to traverse the elements using indexes from 11 (which is bucky.length-1) down to 0, otherwise the for loop attempts to access bucky[bucky.length] same as bucky[12] which throws the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 1):

Your array `bucky[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};` has **12** elements its length is **12** but you can not try to read the element **bucky[12]**, you can go from **bucky[0 ] to bucky[11]** OR from **bucky[11] to bucky[0]**  what ever your logic is..

Answer (score 1):

The for loop starts with `i = bucky.length.` Let me explain why this is out of bounds.
Mathematically the nth element is at index n-1. 1st element is at index 1-1 (0)

So visually if your array bucky is [1,2,3,4,5] ,  `bucky[0]` == 0,  `bucky[1]` == 1, etc up to `bucky[4]` == 5.
Your array has 5 elements so it's length is 5, but the last element is at index 4.

So to the index of the last element in the array is `bucky.length-1` . From here you can see that if you try to access the index at `bucky.length` you will be accessing an index that is beyond the last index in the array.
Your for loop is starting with `i = bucky.length`, hence why starting it with `i=bucky.length-1` fixes the problem.